# I keep getting "Key is not a string: undefined" error

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, selenium

I am totally new at this, I am not sure why I keep getting key is not a string: undefined when I run my code. Could you help me and if you see any other thing wrong feel free to point it out or if you know any course or website where I can learn js and/or selenium webdriver, it would be great. Thank you.

`code`

```
const driverSleep = require("c:/Users/Karla Mieses/Desktop/AutomatedTesting/actions/timeOut");
const name = require("c:/Users/Karla Mieses/Desktop/AutomatedTesting/actions/createName");
const clickPlanDesign = require("c:/Users/Karla Mieses/Desktop/AutomatedTesting/actions/clickPlanDesign");

async function multipleGroups(driver, By, until, Key) {

    //wait 500ms
    await driverSleep();
    //Click on Plan Modifiers
    await clickPlanDesign(driver, until, By);
    //wait 500ms
    await driverSleep();
    //Click on Group
    (await driver).findElement(By.xpath(`//a[@title='Alt+G']`)).click();
    //wait 500ms
    await driverSleep();

    async function diffGroups(driver, By, Key) {
        const group = [`GROUPNAMENULL`, `BYSNULL`, `MAXPESPQTYNULL`, `MAXPRESPVALUENULL`, `SALESTAXNULL`, `PRESCRIBERCHECKNULL`, `ALLFIELDS`];
        const groupName = [``, `name2`, `name3`, `name4`, `name`, `name6`, `name7`];
        const benefitYearStart = [`01/01/1900`, ``, `01/01/1900`, `01/01/1900`, `01/01/1900`, `01/01/1900`, `01/01/1900`, `01/01/1900`];
        const maxPrespQty = [`0`, `1`, ``, `999`, `999`, `999`, `999`];
        const maxPresType = [`BY`, `CY`, `CM`, ``, `BY`, `BY`, `BY`];
        const salesTax = [`0`, `1`, `2`, `0`, ``, `1`, `2`];
        const prescriberCheck = [`0`, `1`, `2`, `0`, `1`, ``, `2`];

        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            //Insert carrier
            (await driver).findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="form_item_groups_carrier_id"]/div[2]/div/span/input`)).sendKeys(`${name}`);
            //Wait 500ms
            await driverSleep();
            //actions
            // (await driver).actions().sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.ARROW_DOWN, Key.RETURN)).perform();
            //wait 500ms
            await driverSleep();
            //Insert group
            (await driver).findElement(By.xpath(`//input[@placeholder='Search by Group Number']`)).sendKeys(group[i]);
            //wait
            await driverSleep();
            //Insert group type
            (await driver).findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="form_item_groups_group_type"]/div[2]/div/span/input`)).sendKeys(`00`, Key.RETURN);
            //wait
            await driverSleep();
            //Insert Group Name
            (await driver).findElement(By.name(`groups_group_name`)).sendKeys(groupName[i]);
            //wait
            await driverSleep();
            //Insert Benefit Year
            (await driver).findElement(By.xpath(`//input[@placeholder='MM/DD/YYYY']`)).sendKeys(benefitYearStart[i]);
            //wait
            await driverSleep();
            //Insert Maximum Prescriptions
            (await driver).findElement(By.name(`groups_max_rx`)).sendKeys(maxPrespQty[i]);
            //wait
            await driverSleep();
            //Insert Prescriptions type
            (await driver).findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="form_item_groups_max_rx"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span/input`)).sendKeys(maxPresType[i], Key.RETURN);
            //wait
            await driverSleep();
            //Insert Sales Tax
            (await driver).findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="form_item_groups_tax_logic"]/div[2]/div/span/input`)).sendKeys(salesTax[i], Key.RETURN);
            //wait
            await driverSleep();
            //Insert Prescriber Check
            (await driver).findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="form_item_groups_prescriber_logic"]/div[2]/div/span/input`)).sendKeys(prescriberCheck[i], Key.RETURN);
            //wait
            await driverSleep();
            //Inserting Plan
            (await driver).findElement(By.name(`groups_plan_list_plan_id`)).sendKeys(`200025`);
            //Wait
            await driverSleep();
            //hit on enter to load plan
            await driver.actions().sendKeys(Key.ENTER).perform();
            //Wait
            await driverSleep();
            //add item
            await (await driver).findElement(By.className(`ant-btn pharmsys_button btn btn-primary btn-sm ant-btn-primary ant-btn-sm`)).click();
            //Wait
            await driverSleep();
            //click on create
            (await driver).findElement(By.className(`ant-btn pharmsys_button pharmsys-button-success ant-btn-button ant-btn-sm`)).click();
            await driverSleep();
        }
    } await diffGroups(driver, By, Key);
} module.exports = multipleGroups;
```

Comment: Any traceback with the error? Can you point out where your exception comes from?

Comment: Are you sure that you used the correct quotes to wrap the strings in array? I see not the correct quote. Seems to be you used "`" instead of single quote.